# run command line command within ruby, using ruby variable

Tags: ruby

I need to run a ruby script to compile and save a csv file, whose path will be determined by the ARGV I give the script. I want ruby to automatically open that file (using `open filepath` inside backticks) at the end, but the filepath variable will be dynamic. How do I give the value of the filepath to the command inside backticks?
Thank you!!

Comment: Is there any reason you absolutely require the back-tick syntax? You could easily accomplish the same with a regular string using `system` or `exec`. You can also use string interpolation within back-ticks anyways.

Comment: I just didn't realize there are different ways to do this. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string interpolation in backticks, just like with double quoted strings:

```
`open #{filepath}`
```

Side note: it’s a good idea to use [`Shellwords.escape`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-escape) so that e.g. spaces inside `filepath` won’t break your code:

```
require "shellwords"

`open #{Shellwords.escape(filepath)}`
```

Comment: I would not recommend backticks here, because it means that Ruby is supposed on the one hand to capture all the stdout of the command, and afterwards throw it away (since you don't store it anywhere). If you really don't want to see the stdout, a `system("open #{Shellwords.escape(filepath)} >/dev/null")` would be more appropriate.